# In Git, is there any way to create a new commit with files in an arbitrary commit?

Tags: git, github

Suppose a git-tree is like below:

A - B - C - D - E
|
A'- B'- C'- X

A has a file `a.txt`
B has files `a.txt` and `b.txt`
C has files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`
... so on

and
A' has a file `aa.txt`
B' has files `aa.txt` and `bb.txt`
C' has files `aa.txt`, `bb.txt` and `cc.txt`

Is there any way to have a commit X consist of the files totally same as those in C?

X has files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`
and X has a history containing A', B' and C'.

What I'd like to do is not like below:

```
git switch C'
git reset --hard C
```

because X should have A', B' and C' in its history
and also not like below

```
git switch C'
git merge C
```

It is more of ..like below:

```
git switch C'
git checkout C (all files)
git commit -m "C' ->C"
```

Comment: Yes you reset the tree to the same state without messing with `HEAD`.

Comment: can I have the way?

Comment: `git checkout C ; git reset --soft C' ; git commit` ? (not tested, try at own risk)

Comment: sorry I added details , I also need the history of A' and B'

Comment: Like @teapot418 said, that's one way to do it or, nowadays, with `git restore` working on `X`: `git checkout X; git restore --worktree --staged --source C -- .; git commit -m "blah blah"`. This will create a commit _after_ `X`.... if you would rather have `X` modified so that it looks just like `C` then `git commit --amend` instead of the commit I used in the previous 1-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge `C` into `X`. Then, undo the merge while keeping the changes from the merge. This is called a **soft reset**.

For clarity, when I am referencing `C'` from your post, I refer to it as "C Prime."

1. `git merge <branch_on_C>`
2. `git reset --soft <blob_on_C_prime>`
3. `git commit`

You are now on your newly-created `Blob X`, without having the attached history of A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

The direct route is to bypass all the worktree churn and just create the commit. Assuming `C'` is the current "cprimesbranch" tip,

```
git update-ref refs/heads/cprimesbranch $(
        git commit-tree -p cprimesbranch -m "C files but cprime parent" C: 
)
```